# does hibernate support self association?

Tags: java, hibernate

i have a problem like in simple words

Animal has childs of type Horse which in turn has more childs of type Horse only.

is it possible in hibernate as i am trying but unable to succed.

Please help.

Comment: What exactly do you want to map? The inheritance of the animal species e.g. Animal > Horse > Pony or some other association among them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for example tree structures are possible in Hibernate.

It would be better if you post some code.